# '%' express any characters, is there any special character for only one character?

Tags: oracle, character, reserved

In Oracle '%' stands for any characters in that position.
Example:

```
Select * from table where id like '%1'
```

This stands for **anything behind** the number 1 : XXXXXXXXXXXX**1** 9999999999**1**.

**Is there any other character to express only **1 character** ?.**

Example of what I mean: (im going to use ~ as that reserved character)

```
Select * from table where id like '~1'
```

In this case only 9**1**, x**1**, X**1**... etc would enter the select, but XX**1** woudn't as you only used one ~.

```
Select * from table where id like '~~~1'
```

xxx**1**, 999**1**, 888**1**, etc....

Hope I explained myself, english is not my native language.

Comment: Why would anyone unrate this question? Isn't it a legit question? or is it because it was not understandable?

Comment: No idea, it looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one *wildcard* character is represented by underscore, `_`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Oracle's [`LIKE` condition documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm):

> #### like_condition::=
>
> [image: LIKE condition syntax]
>
> In this syntax:
>
> - `char1` is a character expression, such as a character column, called the **search** value.
> - `char2` is a character expression, usually a literal, called the **pattern**.
> - `esc_char` is a character expression, usually a literal, called the **escape** character.
>
> [...]
>
> The pattern can contain special pattern-matching characters:
>
> - An underscore (`_`) in the pattern matches exactly one character (as opposed to one byte in a multibyte character set) in the value.
> - A percent sign (`%`) in the pattern can match zero or more characters (as opposed to bytes in a multibyte character set) in the value. The pattern '%' cannot match a null.

Use an `_` underscore.